# onclick with Cakephp html input

Tags: javascript, html, cakephp, input, onclick

I need help, I'm using CakePHP and its html helper. I need to select all in the input field when I click in the input field.

JavaScript:

```
`<script type="text/javascript">
   function SelectAll(id)
    {
      document.getElementById(id).focus();
      document.getElementById(id).select();
    }
</script>`
```

Php:

```
 `<?php echo $html->input('Listing/client_name', array('size' => '15','id' => 'client_name', "onclick'=>'SelectAll('client_name');", 'value'=>'Seller Name', 'class'=> 'font_display_normal' ))?>`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a syntax error, onclick must be a key on array.

```
"onclick'=>'SelectAll('client_name');"
```

should be:

```
'onclick'=> 'SelectAll("client_name");'
```

try:

```
`<?php echo $html->input('Listing/client_name', array('size' => '15','id' => 'client_name', 'onclick'=> 'SelectAll("client_name");' , 'value'=>'Seller Name', 'class'=> 'font_display_normal' ))?>`
```

Comment: Hey, thanx!! This in embarrassing! Hahaha thank you for the help!! It works 100%!